# Sum of Binomial Random Variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

> Seventy percent of rivets from vendor A meet a certain strength specification, and 80% of rivets from vendor B meet the same specification. If 515 rivets are purchased from each vendor, what is the probability that more than 775 of the rivets meet the specifications?

What is incorrect in the following:

Let
$A \sim Bin(515,.7)$, $B \sim Bin(515,.8)$ and $W = A+B$

$P(W \geq 775) = P\bigl(\dfrac{W-E(W)}{\sqrt{V(W)}} \geq \dfrac{775-772.5}{\sqrt{190.55}} \bigr) =P\bigl(Z \geq .1811071 \bigr)= .4281417$

Is this correct? My homework is telling me it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a normal approximation for both $A$ and $B$, we have $$A \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu_A = 360.5, \sigma_A^2 = 108.15), \\ B \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu_B = 412, \sigma_B^2 = 82.4).$$  Therefore, $$W = A+B \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu_W = 772.5, \sigma_W^2 = 190.55).$$  Using continuity correction, $$\Pr[W > 775] \approx \Pr\left[\frac{W - \mu_W}{\sigma_W} > \frac{775.5 - 772.5}{\sqrt{190.55}}\right] \approx 0.413976.$$  Note we want $\Pr[W > 775]$, not $\Pr[W \ge 775]$, thus the continuity correction adds $1/2$ to $775$.

The exact probability using the binomial model is $0.4161678647791356\ldots$, calculated using a computer.  The error is therefore $0.00219171$, which is more than $5$ times smaller than without the continuity correction.